# How to make a drinkable item for minecraft 1.15.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I want to make a drinkable item in minecraft, but I keep running into an error. The thing is is that I am trying to make a class that will override the eating function and replace it with drinking. I don't understand, but it seems like `EnumAction` doesn't exist anymore. Are there other alternative ways to override the eating function to create this item (or any errors in my code)?

```java
package com.saucygames05.morecandymod.objects.items;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class DrinkItem extends Item {
    public DrinkItem() {
        super(null);
        this.setRegistryName("apple_juice");
        }
    @Override
        public EnumAction getItemUseAction () {
            return EnumAction.DRINK;
        }
}
```

I need at least a few answers before I go insane trying to figure it out for another week lmao.

Comment: I have this problem too right now. Instead of creating my own item class, I registered a customized MilkBucketItem. It is drinkable, but it also removes all the effects from the player, which I don't want it to.

Comment: I have found the way to fix your solution, but at the end of drinking there still is a short audible eating sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring `net.minecraft.item` I realized that apparently, `EnumAction` is now replaced with `UseAction`, while `getItemUseAction` is now replaced with `getUseAction`. The solution to your problem might be a class like this:

```java
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.item.UseAction;

public class DrinkableItem extends Item {
    public DrinkableItem(Properties properties) {
        super(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public UseAction getUseAction(ItemStack stack) {
        return UseAction.DRINK;
    }
}
```

However, a brief but audible eating / burping sound is still present after the use of such item (screenshot below). I will update the answer if I find a way to fix that.

[image: Screenshot with eating sound in subtitles]

Comment: This helped a lot, but how would i add effects after you drink the item?

Comment: @SaucyCodes05 When registering your item, register it as `food` and specify the `effect` as part of that `food`.

Comment: How would you give the player an empty glass?